# How to easily resize strings in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have declared a string in the testbench code. However, I find that it is not simple to assign value to it. Here is the test code:

```
process  
    variable str : string(1 to 64);
begin
    str := "hello world";
    report str;
    wait;
end process;
```

Why can't string contain index 0 in it? Also, how can I assign a string of any length to this variable since it won't be easy to make every string I assign to it, equal 64 characters by putting in white spaces.

EDIT:

This is what I came up with at the end, is there a simpler way to do this in VHDL?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_misc.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity experiment_4 is
end entity;

architecture beh of experiment_4 is
  procedure write_string(strout: out string; constant strin: in string) is
  variable str : string(strout'range);
  variable l,r: integer;
  begin                 
    if strin'length > strout'length then
      assert false report "the specified string cannot fit into the specified variable" severity failure;
    else
      for i in strout'range loop
        strout(i) := ' ';   
      end loop;
      strout(strin'range) := strin;
    end if;    
  end procedure;    
begin
    
    process  
        variable str : string(1 to 64);
    begin       
        write_string(str, "hello world");
        report str;
        wait;
    end process;
    
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite certain to understand what you are trying to do here. Maybe there is a bit of a XY problem in the first place. Nonetheless, I'll try to answer questions we have so far.

`String`s are defined by standard as:

```
  type STRING is array (POSITIVE range <>) of CHARACTER;
```

and `positive` is defined as:

```
  subtype POSITIVE is INTEGER range 1 to INTEGER'HIGH;
```

That's why you cannot use index 0: by definition, `string` indices are from 1 onwards. When declaring variables/signals/subtypes, you may only be more restrictive than the original range.

In VHDL, strings are no more than arrays, the very same way `std_logic_vectors` are arrays. You should think about assign strings the same way you do when assigning (part of) logic arrays.

Here in your example code, you seem to want to assign a variable-length string literal to a (constrained) string variable. You do it with a procedure that pads the input argument. You could as well create a function, which may be clearer:

```
function padded(s: string; len: positive := 64; p: character := ' ') return string
is
  alias xs: string(1 to s'length) is s;
  variable ret : string(1 to len) := (others => p);
begin
  if xs'length >= len then
    ret := xs(1 to len);
  else
    ret(1 to xs'length) := xs;
  end if;
  return ret;
end function;
```

Then:

```
process  
    variable str : string(1 to 64);
begin       
    str := padded("hello world", str'length);
    report str;
    wait;
end process;
```

Another option is to use `access` to a `string`. `Access` is VHDL equivalent of pointers, with the nice feature that actual array constraints are attached to the targetted instance, so they may change.

It happens standard defines such thing in **std.textio**, `line`, which is defined as:

```
type LINE is access STRING;
```

`Line` type definition comes with procedures that are able to append text to it, called `write`.

```
procedure WRITE (L: inout LINE; VALUE: in STRING;
                 JUSTIFIED: in SIDE:= RIGHT; FIELD: in WIDTH := 0);
```

Note `write` is overloaded for many other `value` types, but I wont include them here, see standard for more.

Notice `write` `L` argument is `inout`. It is actually modified by the procedure. Behind the scenes, `write` reallocates the targetted `string` object to new size.

Typical usage is for constructing variable-length message:

```
use std.textio.all;

-- ...

function describe_number(v: in integer) return string is
  variable ret: line := new string'("");
begin
  write(ret, string'("Passed argument is: "));
  write(ret, v);
  if v >= 1000 then
    write(ret, string'(", this is a lot !"));
  end if;
  return ret.all;
end function describe_number;

-- ...

process  
begin       
  report describe_number(1);
  report describe_number(1000);
  wait;
end process;
```

Answer (score 0):

All right, this is the final solution, I don't think there is a better way but let me know if there is one.

```
  procedure write_string(strout: out string; constant strin: in string) is
  begin
    assert strin'length <= strout'length
    report "the specified string size " & integer'image(strin'length) & " cannot fit into the specified variable size " & integer'image(strout'length)
    severity failure;
    for i in strout'range loop
      strout(i) := ' ';
    end loop;
    strout(strin'range) := strin;
  end procedure;
```